# Editing csv file Python 3 - matching file content to the print output

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I am having an issue with getting the contents of created csv file to show up as the print output.

Code:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    filewriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 2 + ['Baked Beans'])
    filewriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])

with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar=',')
     for row in filereader:
         print(', '.join(row))
```

Output:

```
Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

`test.csv` file:

```
Spam Spam ,Baked Beans,
Spam ,Lovely Spam, ,Wonderful Spam,
```

*Notice the weird commas.*

Desired contents of `test.csv`

```
Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this output is because you are using comma `quotechar=','` to quote fields containing space which is your delimiter. That being said what you want is use `,` as delimiter which is the default [delimiter value](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter).

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    filewriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 2 + ['Baked Beans'])
    filewriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

The same thing apply if you want to read your `csv` file.